# Performance test for if statement branch

Tags: java, performance

Is there any difference in performance between:

```
public int method()
{
    x = 1;
    if (x == 0)
       System.out.println("something");
    return 1;
}
```

And

```
public int method()
{
    x = 1;
    if (x == 0)
       System.out.println("something");
    else
       return 1;

    return 7; //this won't happen because x is 1
}
```

As you can notice I used an `else` in the second example. I do not know if the branching return is faster than the normal return.

Comment: You could compare the bytecode generated in both examples.

Comment: With micro-optimizations like this it's really easy: if you don't know, you don't need it. People who do know find out by performing profiling analysis and draw their conclusions from that. The reason they do this is because it has proven to be a problem that should be addressed, no matter how minor. It's one of those things where you don't know until you need it but by needing it, you will know.

Comment: There should not be a difference. If so ever it can be it would be very very very negligible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's see the jvm instructions :

the first method one if branch:

```
     public int ifmethod();
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  iconst_1
 2  putfield ifperf.main.x : int [22]
 5  aload_0 [this]
 6  getfield ifperf.main.x : int [22]
 9  ifne 20
12  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [24]
15  ldc <String "something"> [30]
17  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [32]
20  iconst_1
21  ireturn
```

the second method with else branch :

```
public int ifelsemethod();
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  iconst_1
 2  putfield ifperf.main.x : int [22]
 5  aload_0 [this]
 6  getfield ifperf.main.x : int [22]
 9  ifne 23
12  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [24]
15  ldc <String "something"> [30]
17  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [32]
20  goto 25
23  iconst_1
24  ireturn
25  bipush 7
27  ireturn
```

As you can see the both method are stricly identic in that case. the answer is at line 9 you have the test ifne ("IF Not Equal goto line XY") so in one case you go at line 20 and in the second at line 23. and then you execute the exact same instruction.

So in one case you will execute 0-9 -> 20,21 and in the other 0-9->23,24